# Correct way check nonce (security) using old Options API

Tags: plugin-development, security, options, settings-api

I am developing plugin for Wordpress.
Firstly I started using Settings API it looks good, but it is little bit complex and it doesn't provide the way to handle options manually.

I have quite complex options structure, it consists dynamic number of items/object each object has multiple fields, and I need to save array of such objects as options, but as I found it is impossible to implement such behavior using Settings API, so I decided to handle all this stuff manually checking what request `GET` or `POST` and use `update_option`.

Maybe there is possible way to implement this using Settings API but I haven't found any.

So I am not sure how to handle security correctly now, Settings API does all under the hood, but in case of Option API I have to everything manually, but I don't how to do this, I tried to find, but nothing.

In case of settings API I used such lines of code

```
  @settings_fields('my-section');
  @do_settings_fields('my-section');

      <table class="form-table"> .... 

  @submit_button();
```

And this code generates hidden nonce field, so I guess wordpress `options.php` page checks this nonce when post request is made.

How to handle all security stuff using Options API.

I would be grateful for any help.